# typename resolution in cases of ambiguity

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was playing with Visual Studio and templates.

Consider this code

```
struct Foo
{
  struct Bar
  {
  };

  static const int Bar=42;
};

template<typename T>
void MyFunction()
{
  typename T::Bar f;  
}

int main()
{
    MyFunction<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this is either Visual Studio 2008 and 11, I get the following error

`error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'f'`

Is Visual Studio correct in this regard ? Is the code violating any standards ?

If I change the code to

```
struct Foo
{
  struct Bar
  {
  };

  static const int Bar=42;
};


void SecondFunction( const int& )
{
}

template<typename T>
void MyFunction()
{
  SecondFunction( T::Bar ); 
}

int main()
{
    MyFunction<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles without any warnings.  In Foo::BLAH a **member** preferred over a **type** in case of conflicts ?

**EDIT  Tests on G++ 4.2.1**

```
struct Foo
{
  static const int Bar=42;
};


void SecondFunction(const int& x)
{
}

template<typename T>
void MyFunction()
{
  int x = Foo::Bar;
}

int main()
{
  MyFunction<Foo>();
  return 0;
}
```

compiles OK.

```
struct Foo
{
  static const int Bar=42;
};


void SecondFunction(const int& x)
{
}

template<typename T>
void MyFunction()
{
  SecondFunction(T::Bar);
}

int main()
{
  MyFunction<Foo>();
  return 0;
}
```

Gives me these errors

**Undefined symbols:
  "Foo::Bar", referenced from:
      void MyFunction()  in cck498aS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: Compiles fine in GCC 4.6.2. I'd blame MS. They're pretty famous for not implementing template lookup in a standard-conforming way. Also, the type is *also* a member -- it's a member *type*.

Comment: Your final error is a linker error, not a compiler error, since you never *defined* `Foo::Bar`. Say `const int Foo::Bar;` to do so.

Comment: Wow.. i learned a lot today.. i think static const int was defined and declared in place

Comment: Nope. It's only declared and initialized in place, but not defined. Often you can get away with it, though, e.g. as long as you don't take its address or anything like that. Static constants can essentially be replaced by their value at compile-time, so they don't always need to "exist" physically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, named entities fall into one of three distinct ontological tiers: *values*, *types* and *templates*.

If a dependent name is of an unknown tier, then *you* must tell the compiler what it is:

- If you say nothing, it's a value.
- If you say `typename`, it's a type.
- If you say `template`, it's a template.

So `T::Bar`, being a dependent name inside the `MyFunction` template, is automatically assumed to refer to a value, hence the `int` member `Foo::Bar`. On the other hand, in the first example, `typename T::Bar` indeed refers to the member *type* `Foo::Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

You see the effect of a not well known rule which exists for C compatibility. In C, unlike in C++, if you define a type as `struct X` or `enum X`, you do *not* introduce the name `X` into the corresponding namespace, but have to refer to the type as `struct X`. For that reason, in C you can additionally define 'X' as something different without triggering conflicting definitions. Now in C++, `struct X` does introduce the name `X` into the corresponding scope. Therefore any other definition of `X` would be flagged as double-definition. However it was deemed important to be able to include C headers where this problem frequently occurs. Therefore a special rule was introduced that whenever you both have a (non-typedef) type definition for `X` and another definition for `X`, this does not lead to an error, but `X` refers to the non-type definition, and to get at the type definition, you have to prefix it with the corresponding type keyword (i.e. `struct X`, `emum X` or `class X`).

In your case, this means that `Foo` contains a type named `class Bar` and a static const int named `Bar`, but no type named `Bar`. Note that the template isn't needed here; a simple global declaration `Bar::Foo foo;` should also fail.